# Unable to set rounded corners on top of activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity class which extends AppCompatActivity.
I want to make it look like a dialog with rounded corners.

Below is the shape code

drawable/dialog_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_left</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_right</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>


    </style>

</resources>
```

settings_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingDial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <!-- Title Bar -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Notification -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"

            >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/notificationSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Notification"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <!-- Notification Time -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Notification Time"

                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:text="07:00 AM"

                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <!-- Music -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"

            >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/Music"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Music"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <!-- Disable Ads -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Categories"

                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:text=">"

                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <!-- Disable Ads -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Favorites"

                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:text=">"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <!-- Disable Ads -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Disable Ads"

                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:text=">"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"/>
```

By doing this I am able to get the following
[image]
But I am not able to get the rounded corners on top.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That's strange. When I execute your code, I get four rounded corners. https://www.christine.nl/pics/device-2016-11-27-213929.png

Comment: On Android 5.1 and higher, I get rounded corners. On Android 4.4, I get rounded corners in the bottom, not at the top. You can try using a different theme.

Comment: @Christine: Thanks a lot for such a quick reply :) and yes you are right, its  having issues only with 4.4. I will try few more themes and update the answer soon

Comment: I had 4 rounded corners in another theme, but then there was a title bar I couldn't get rid of.